# Limiting traffic to/from VM

Tags: vpn, lan, wan, network-traffic, traffic-filtering

I have a headless Ubuntu VM running on an Ubuntu host.  I want to limit the VM's WAN traffic to a specific IP address range only (e.g., 156.*.*.*), and if servers on that specific IP address range are down, then the VM will not be able to get any internet access at all, not even over port 22* when I SSH** into the VM from somewhere else on my LAN.  Possible?

(* if that's even possible)
(** I want to continue to be able to SSH into the VM from my LAN only)

EDIT:
My LAN is on 192.168.1.X, and the gateway is 192.168.1.1.  The VMs have their own IP addresses.  When 156.X.X.X is up (this is a server that's not on my network), there should be two-way traffic over probably a handful of ports.  The VM in question should allow two-way traffic over the usual SSH ports to machines on 192.168.X.X always.  The VM in question should also have two-way traffic with 156.X.X.X, and no other address ranges.

Comment: Its likely possible, but your question is very ambiguous and the answer depends on your network topology (and might require scripting/keepalives) . Can you advise your network topology especially gateways and the relationship of "156" to everytjing else.  Also, how "world accessible" should the device be when "156" is up?

Comment: The **basic** way to do this is to just use the firewall on the VM to allow traffic in/out to `192.168.1.0/24` and `156.0.0.0/8` and deny all else, maybe limit to specific ports as well. Depending on your flavor of ubuntu, you would probably use `ufw` or `iptables`